# Как предотвратить повторный запуск задания в агенте?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2014
В агенте создано задание, которое выполняется каждые 10 сек. Суть задания заключается в обработке данных, накопившихся после выполнения предыдущего задания. Задание написано на T-SQL. В зависимости от объёма данных задание не всегда успевает выполниться за 10 сек. Если до окончания выполнения задания запустить его ещё раз, то нарушается алгоритм обработки данных. 
Вопрос: 
Как выяснить, выполнение задания завершено или ещё нет? Может в SQL Server 2014 есть какие-то средства для анализа завершения задания (переменные, например)?

Comment: Создайте таблицу и в ней отмечайтесь.

Comment: Задание не запустится второй раз пока не закончится предыдущее выполнение

Comment: Насчёт создания таблицы понятно. Я ожидал, что есть штатные средства проверки завершения задания. А проверить поточнее реакцию системы на повторный запуск надо... Отпишусь по результатам.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin офоримите в виде ответа?

Answer (score 1):

Да, Denis Rubashkin прав - задание не запускается, пока не закончится предыдущее выполнение. Вопрос закрыт.